# How can I have multiple SplitPanes including children with javaFX?

Tags: javafx, duplicates, containers, nodes, children

My structure:

```
AnchorPane
 | 
 ScrollPane
  |
  FlowPane
   |
   SplitPane
    |
    StackedBarChart
    TableView
```

How can I, duplicate my `SplitPane` with its children for a *unknown numbers* of duplicates?

How can i set for each copy new variable names?

In Scene Builder i right click on `SplitPane` and select `Duplicate`. But, the problem is the number of duplicates is not available before writting the program and is not known until runtime.

Comment: I still don't get your question. What do you mean by `duplicate my SplitPane for a unknown numbers of duplicates` ? Can you please elaborate.

Comment: I have a SplitPane containing StackedBarChart and a TableView. For example, i will show in it machine data . One machine datas in one Chart and tableView. Now i want to duplicate first SplitPane with its chidrens for displaying the next machine datas. The number of machines is variable.

Comment: Yes, I get that. But do you just want to add `StackedBarChart` to one part of the SplitPane and `TableView` on the other? Or, the requirement is something different?

Comment: StackedBarChart to one part of the SplitPane and TableView on the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach for this would be to create a separate FXML for `SplitPane`, load it as many times as you want and add it to your `FlowPane`.

Let us call the new fxml as `split.fxml`. A controller for the fxml called as `SplitController`

Then,we will load this fxml as many times as required, get the root and add it to the `FlowPane`, which is now present in a separate fxml.

Let us call the main fxml as `container.fxml`. A controller for the fxml called as `ContainerController`

Answering some of your questions :

> How can I, duplicate my SplitPane with its children for a unknown numbers of duplicates?

Just load the fxml as many times you need.

> How can i set for each copy new variable names?

You have the controller, you can identify it with a variable. You may also set a `class` or `id` to the splitpane.

The complete code...

**split.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.StackedBarChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>

<SplitPane fx:id="splitPane" dividerPositions="0.25" prefHeight="363.0" prefWidth="773.0" fx:controller="SplitController"  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <items>
        <TableView fx:id="tableView" prefHeight="458.0" prefWidth="251.0">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
                <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
            </columns>
        </TableView>
        <StackedBarChart fx:id="stackedBarChart" prefHeight="210.0" prefWidth="107.0">
            <xAxis>
                <CategoryAxis fx:id="categoryAxis" side="BOTTOM" label="Year" />
            </xAxis>
            <yAxis>
                <NumberAxis fx:id="numberAxis" side="LEFT" label="Value"/>
            </yAxis>
        </StackedBarChart>
    </items>
</SplitPane>
```

**SplitController.java**

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.StackedBarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class SplitController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private SplitPane splitPane;

    @FXML
    private StackedBarChart<String, Number> stackedBarChart;

    @FXML
    private TableView<String> tableView;

    @FXML
    private CategoryAxis categoryAxis;

    @FXML
    private NumberAxis numberAxis;

    private ObservableList<String> tableList;

    private ObservableList<Integer> chartValueList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public void setTableList(ObservableList<String> tableList) {
        this.tableList = FXCollections.observableList(tableList);
    }

    public void setChartValueList(ObservableList<Integer> chartValueList) {
        this.chartValueList = FXCollections.observableList(chartValueList);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

    public void setChart(){
        XYChart.Series<String,Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series();

        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("January", chartValueList.get(0)));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("February", chartValueList.get(1)));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("March", chartValueList.get(2)));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("April", chartValueList.get(3)));

        XYChart.Series<String,Number> series2 = new XYChart.Series();

        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("January", chartValueList.get(0)));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("February", chartValueList.get(1)));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("March", chartValueList.get(2)));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("April", chartValueList.get(3)));

        stackedBarChart.getData().addAll(series1, series2);
    }
}
```

**container.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>

<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ContainerController">
   <center>
        <ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <content>
                <FlowPane fx:id="flowPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="353.0" prefWidth="745.0">

                </FlowPane>
            </content>
        </ScrollPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

**ContainerController.java**

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ContainerController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane anchorPane;

    @FXML
    private ScrollPane scrollPane;

    @FXML
    private FlowPane flowPane;

    private final int NUMBER_OF_COPIES = 5;
    private final int NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 10;
    private ObservableList<String> tableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private ObservableList<Integer> chartValueList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        try {
            for(int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_COPIES; i++) {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/split.fxml"));
                SplitPane pane = loader.load();
                SplitController controller = loader.getController();
                fillChartValueList();
                controller.setChartValueList(chartValueList);
                controller.setChart();
                flowPane.getChildren().add(pane);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void fillChartValueList(){

        // clear previous values
        chartValueList.clear();

        Random rand = new Random();
        int min = 1000;
        int max = 8000;


        for(int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_ROWS; i++) {
            int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
            chartValueList.add(randomNum);
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.java** - to load the container, set it to a stage and show

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

    public Main() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException{

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/container.fxml"));
        Parent parent = loader.load();
        ContainerController controller = loader.getController();

        Scene scene = new Scene(parent, 600, 600);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Note** - The `TableView` is empty as I didn't consider it important to fill it, as per the question.

Comment: I think what Gerhard is actually trying to do is to create many instances of the entire thing within a scene, using the fxml as a template.  For example, he has a list of machines (the number of which he knows at runtime, but not when designing the GUI) and he wants to display a separate graph and table for each of the machines. But i could be wrong, maybe Gerhard could comment to clarify.

Comment: I missed [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623849/how-can-i-multiple-duplicate-a-splitpane-including-childrens-with-javafx/29624706?noredirect=1#comment47391633_29623849) as it was edited later. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, i wants to display a separate graph and table for each of the machines.
(the number of which i knows at runtime)

Comment: I have found this:
*****
Don't works:
flowPane.getChildren().add(new SplitPane(splitPane.setId(machine)));
*****
Works:
flowPane.getChildren().add(new SplitPane(splitPane));

Comment: @GerhardLaib I have edited my answer, please have a look and let me know in case you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you very much @ItachiUchiha.
Ist the perfect solution for my problem!

Comment: @GerhardLaib Glad to help!! Welcome to StackOverflow. [Please take a tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Ask questions, comment, answer some of them, upvote them, accept answers and have fun in the community. :)

Comment: Sorry, i can't accept the answer, because i have as beginner of StackExchange not enough Points ;-)
I have 5 Points, need 15 ;-)

Comment: @GerhardLaib You are trying to `upvote`  the answer instead of `accepting` it. Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand the difference :)

Answer (score 0):

That works:

```
    SplitPane sp=new SplitPane(splitPane);
    sp.setId(machine);
    flowPane.getChildren().add(new SplitPane(sp));
```